# The variable that broke the eclipse's back : maximum number of variables?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables, out-of-memory

I am encountering astounding trouble...

It appears that when adding a new variable in one of my classes (android application, java, Eclipse), the AVD crashes when opening the corresponding activity.

It works fine if I decide to remove another variable instead, whatever it is. It doesn't seem to matter if the variable is int or double.

So it looks like as if there was a maximum number of variables ?? (I know it looks weird but...)

Works fine with the same project on another computer (using Eclipse, but differente version).

Does anyone has the begining of an explanation ?
I would appreciate any help...

Thank you !

```
    05-12 12:15:49.107: W/dalvikvm(674): Invalid reg type for array index (1174247616)
05-12 12:15:49.107: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/preference/Scoresdetail;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
05-12 12:15:49.136: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x46 at 0x14ec
05-12 12:15:49.136: W/dalvikvm(674): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/preference/Scoresdetail;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
05-12 12:15:49.146: W/dalvikvm(674): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/preference/Scoresdetail;
05-12 12:15:49.146: W/dalvikvm(674): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/preference/Scoresdetail;)
05-12 12:15:49.146: D/AndroidRuntime(674): Shutting down VM
05-12 12:15:49.146: W/dalvikvm(674): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674): java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.preference.Scoresdetail
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-12 12:15:49.196: E/AndroidRuntime(674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 12:15:50.996: D/dalvikvm(674): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5697 objects / 318752 bytes in 1227ms
05-12 12:15:52.056: I/Process(674): Sending signal. PID: 674 SIG: 9
```

and just for the record, when the app crashes I get :

```
The application (package name) has stop unexpectedly. Please try again...
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste in the stack trace.  No stack trace and we have to guess.

Comment: Do you see any error messages or similar?

Comment: You can get your stack trace via LogCat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Sorry about that ! My post is edited, thank you again for you help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this link !! It is unbelievable that it is limited to 155 variables... Looks very small.

Comment: @Simon, please vote to close this as a dupe.